# How to extract dll from GAC and install the same on other computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I am using asp.net with c#.I am using log4net.ll and it is being referenced by the one of the project in my computer, when I run that it is completely working fine on my computer and logs the desire message into text file. 
But now I want to configure same project into other computer, so copied entire source code into that computer. Then on second computer when I run the solution it shows an error reference not found 
so copied a dll from below location from my computer and paste into bin directory of second computer and add reference from bin to that application on second computer, so I was able to build the solution 
successfully. but problem occurred when I was trying to view that on web browser of second computer it shows me error that assemble could not load log4net.dll or its one the dependencies could not be loaded.

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\log4net\1.2.10.0__692fbea5521e1304\log4net.dll
version of log4net.dll which I am using is 1.2.10.0.
```

Is there any way to configure on second computer or any other way to extract log4net.dll from one computer to install into other computer?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are some dependencies for log4net.dll which are available on the first computer. Try turning on the fusion logs and see what dll\file that assembly is looking for and is not able to load.

Also just check that log4net.dll have been installed using some installer in first computer, if yes than try running the same installer on the second machine.

Hope this helps!